Why does the Lax-Milgram theorem require coercivity?
If $B$ is a bilinear form on a Hilbert space $H$ that is continuous and coercive, meaning there exists a constant $c > 0$ so
$$B(u,u) \geq c\|u\|^2 \quad \forall u \in H$$
then the Lax-Milgram theorem says there exists $x \in H$ such that $B(u,x) = \langle u, w\rangle$ for a unique vector $w \in H$.
Is there any intuition for why coercivity is important for this theorem to be true? The coercivity condition looks unnatural to me.

I suggest you look at the proof of the theorem. In short, you can write $B(u,x) = (u,Ax)$ for a bounded linear operator $A$ and now you need coercivity of $B$ (and thus of $A$) to show that $A$ is invertible.

@EvangelopoulosFoivos I saw the proof but I was looking for an intuitive reason why we might need this condition. Unless it is just a necessary technical condition?

Coercivity implies boundedness from below, which is closely related to convertibility, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/759630/invertible-iff-bounded-below-and-dense-range
